# Проверка по слову

Tags: java, строки, scanner

Как сделать, чтобы когда вводишь слово, оно делало проверку, и если слово совпадает в условии if(), то выполняло команду?

```
public void showInfoAccount() {
    String showInfo;
    do {

        System.out.print(INPUT_SHOW);
        showInfo = sc.nextLine();

        if (showInfo == "Show information")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < resultPeopleWallet().length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Our clients:");
                System.out.println(resultPeopleWallet()[i].name1);
            }
        } else if(showInfo.isEmpty() || showInfo != "Show information") {
            System.out.print(INPUT_SHOW);
        }
    } while (showInfo.isEmpty() || showInfo != "Show information");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java нельзя сравнивать строки по `==`, т.к. в этом случае вы сравниваете ссылки на объекты, а не сами строковые значения. Замените `showInfo == "Show information"` на `showInfo.equals("Show information")`.